# cordova - open pdf file externally

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, pdf, mobile

I'm having difficulties to open a PDF file externally to my app made with cordova. I have already made a research about this topic but I could not find any solution.

This is what I have already tried.

```
window.open('path/to/test.pdf', '_blank');
```

and

```
window.open('path/to/test.pdf', "_system", "location=no")
```

but none of this worked, I have already installed cordova-plugin-file, cordova-file-transfer and cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
But couldn't make it.

Comment: This should help you out - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations